# Using String::from with variables

Tags: rust

Is there a way to use String::from with variables? I tried using it similarly to println!(), but doesn't seem to work.

```
String::from("[INFO]: {}", message)

Expected:
// Returns: "[INFO]: My info message here"

Got:
// Error: argument unexpected
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `format!`

Answer (score 0):

Rust doesn’t really practice variadic functions because we have big metaprogramming potential: modern generic system and about 6 types of macros.

In this case you need the `format` macro:

```rust
format!("[INFO]: {}", message)
```